# add new key to dict - KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
    def fibMemo(n):
        pad = {0:0, 1:1}  
        if n not in pad:
           print 'Not in dict ,adding', n, n-1, n-2
           pad[n] = pad[n-1] + pad[n-2]
       else:
           print pad[n]
    return 

   for i in range(0,31):
     fibMemo(i)
```

Line 4: Returns KeyError:2 , but I 'm adding a new key Value in case the key doesn't exist. Just started with Python today so might excuse the ignorance. Output

```
    Error:
    0 
    1
    Not in dict ,adding 2 1 0 
    Not in dict ,adding 3 2 1
     Line 5: KeyError: 2
```

i=3 run before i=2 is finished.

Comment: Please consider adding example input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You put the initialization of the dict inside the function body.

So each time the function gets executed, the items go back to 0:0 and 1:1.

When fibMemo(3) is called, it will enter line 5, which will be:

```
pad[3]=pad[2]+pad[1]
```

Since pad[2] was added but later wiped out during initialization of pad.  It gives the key error.

You should consider moving the `pad={}` before the function definition.

Comment: Nope that didn't help either

Comment: @Raj yep, it won't work.  please check out the new answer.  I think that might be the reason.